# Lightning comp throws error after summer '19

Tags: lightning-community, summer19

We have lightning components which are fetching user data from apex. After sandbox upgraded to preview summer'19 these components are throwing error when trying to edit. 
error screenshot - [image]
Is anybody aware about the reason and resolution.

Comment: did you check access? If the user has access for these fields? ContactID, FirstName and so on?

Comment: contactid on User is typically for use in Partner Portals, so I'd also see if something has changed there

Comment: @mPeixoto - this error is for system admin and yes has access to everything

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced this same issue in one my of custom lightning component. Where it was throwing the same error - There is no such column "ContactId" on User entity;

After struggling the whole day I got a solution for this.

**It is just to recompile APEX Classes.**

**Steps to fix it:**

1. Login to Salesforce org
2. Go to setup.
3. Enter "Apex Classes" in the quick search. And then click "Apex Classes".
4. You will see "Compile all classes" link there, just go and press it.
5. Once it completes, go to the component and make the changes and save it. Now it should not show any error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think we already did that but did not work for us. Another thing this error is not consistent it occurs randomly (around once/twice in a day). As a workaround what I do is comment out the apex code save desired changes at component side and restore apex.